# Can't add layers dynamically to layer group when click checkboxes using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

my issue is I can't remove layer of each checkbox, I had already post this issue, unfortunately I didn't get any answer. I'm trying now to use layer group which I add to it layer for each clicked checkbox, but when I tried to remove each layer, it remove the last one, so I noticed that the layers are not added to layer group. So how to add layers to layer group dynamically, in other words
how to add layer each time I clicked on a given checkbox? Can you help me please to figure out what is the problem? Any help is appreciated. Here is a snippet of code:

**php file:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$('input[id^="DisplayCheckbox"]').on('click',function() 
{
    parent = $(this).val();
    Coord = $(this).parents('#' + parent).find("li.Liste").text();
    window.valChk = $(this).val();
         
            if($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                valChk = $(this).val();
                
                $.drawPoly(Coord);

            }else
            {       
                $.removePoly(valChk);
                  
            }
        
});

});
        
</script>
```

**external jquery file:**

```js
$.drawPoly = function(data)
 {
      data = $.parseJSON(data);
              
      var geojsonFeature = 
     {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
           "type": "Feature",
           "geometry": {
           "type": data.type,
           "coordinates": data.coordinates
                        }
                     }]
      };

              
      window.poly=L.geoJson(geojsonFeature);
      poly.id = valChk;
      layerGrp=L.layerGroup([poly]);
      addLayer(valChk);
  
};
 
 function addLayer(id){
    layerGrp.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if(layer.id == id){
          layerGrp.addLayer(layer).addTo(map);
          map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
          console.log(layer._leaflet_id);
        }

    });
   }

  $.removePoly = function(id)
  {
        layerGrp=L.layerGroup([poly]);
        
        layerGrp.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            
            if(layer.id == id)
            {
              console.log(layer._leaflet_id);
              layerGrp.removeLayer(layer);
            }
        });
    
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42275572/5108796) to your previous question on that issue is still valid for the code you posted here: you seem to have a **scoping** issue (actually, several of them).

To be more specific, your `layerGrp` variable is used globally, and re-assigned within `$.removePoly` (statement `layerGrp=L.layerGroup([poly])`). Therefore you lose reference to the previous layers you added to map in `addLayer`, and you can no longer remove them.

Your code is quite overly complicated, making it difficult to understand what it does.

Once you simplify it, I am sure you will be able to solve your issue.

Comment: yep @ghybs you're right, I'm trying to make it more simple, and I will tell you if I solve the issue or not :). About this line layerGrp=L.layerGroup([poly]) in remove function, I already delete it but still not working, so I think that layer group doesn't save layers